# binding data to angular checkbox

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, checkbox

I managed to bind the data from `this.empDetails.services` correctly on the UI, checkboxes are checked correctly, and also listed all the checkboxes options.

However, the data are not pushed to the serviceFormArray, when I click update without any changes to the checkbox, `this.updateServicesForm.value` is empty.

I have to uncheck those checked checkboxes and then check it again so that it will push to the `formarray`.

I tried a few changes, but to no avail, can someone suggest what is the correct code to archived what I need? Thank you so much.
**HTML**

```
<form action="javascript:" [formGroup]="updateSvcForm">
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let service of servicesOptions; let i=index">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="checkbox-color checkbox-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" id={{service.value}} [value]="service.value" (change)="onCheckChange($event)" [checked]=isSelected(service.value)>
        <label for={{service.value}}>
          {{service.description}}
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <button class="btn btn-primary m-b-0 ripple light" (click)="updateServices()">Update</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Component.TS**

```
sservicesOptions = [
  { description: '1. Sweeping', value: 'sweeping' },
  { description: '2. Mopping', value: 'mopping' },
  { description: '3. Windows', value: 'windows' },
  { description: '4. Washing Clothes', value: 'washingclothes' },
];


this.updateSvcForm= this.fb.group({
  sservices: new FormArray([]),
});

onCheckChange(event) {
  const sservicesFormArray: FormArray =
    this.updateSvcForm.get('sservices') as FormArray;


  if (event.target.checked) {
    sservicesFormArray.push(new FormControl(event.target.value));
  }
  else {
    let i: number = 0;
    sservicesFormArray.controls.forEach((ctrl: FormControl) => {
      if (ctrl.value == event.target.value) {
        sservicesFormArray.removeAt(i);
        return;
      }
      i++;
    });
  }
}

isSelected(sserviceOption) {
  return this.empDetails.services.indexOf(serviceOption) >= 0;
}
    console.log(this.updateSvcForm.value);
  }
```

**Data from this.empDetails.services API return**

```
sservices: Array(2)
0: "mopping"
1: "washingclothes"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: how do you fill `this.EmployeeDetails`  ? can you show more code please

Comment: Just a normal api return. The return result is as shown in the last part of the post

Comment: can you show how do you get it from the api ? are you using `updateServicesForm` in HTML ?  (is it `updateSvcForm` ?)

Comment: Yes its updateSvcForm. FormGroupName in html

Comment: await this.employeeService.getEmployeeDetails(this.Employeeuuid).subscribe((res) => {
      this.EmployeeDetails = res as Employee[];

Comment: Any other suggestion? How people handle checkboxes insert and upsate correctly in angular?

Comment: checkboxes are inherently true / false form controls.  Choose a different control (ie multiselect) or find a way to work within that basic framework that your control is a true false control.

Comment: with 
this.updateSvcForm= this.fb.group({
  sservices: new FormArray([]),
});
you overwrite your reference to this form group from html?

Answer (score 6):

The reason for this, is that you are using `checked` to mark which checkboxes should be checked, they have no correlation to your form array, so if you do not touch the checkboxes, the formarray will correctly be empty.

I can come up with a couple options to solve this... also the following changes:

change function could be changed to this:

```
onCheckChange(event) {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    this.ssArray.push(this.fb.control(event.target.value));
  }
  else {
   this.ssArray.removeAt(this.ssArray.value.findIndex(x => x === event.target.value))
  }
}
```

Doesn't matter how you do it, your way works as well :) I also like using `FormBuilder` (here injected as `fb`).

I like to use a getter in this case:

```
get ssArray() {
  return this.updateSvcForm.get('sservices') as FormArray;
}
```

The options I can think of:

1. add a `checked` property to the objects in your array `sservicesOptions`
2. Keep your `isSelected` function, but add the chosen options to your formarray initially

---

I like option 1 best, so add a `checked` property to the objects:

```
servicesOptions = [
  { description: '1. Sweeping', value: 'sweeping', checked: false },
  { description: '2. Mopping', value: 'mopping', checked: false },
  { description: '3. Windows', value: 'windows', checked: false },
  { description: '4. Washing Clothes', value: 'washingclothes', checked: false },
];
```

Then when you build the form, change the checked status for those that should be preselected, and also add the values that should be checked to your form array:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.updateSvcForm = this.fb.group({
    sservices: this.fb.array([]),
  });
  // change the checked status for the checkboxes that should be checked
  this.servicesOptions.map(x => 
    this.empDetails.services.indexOf(x) >= 0 ? x.checked = true : x.checked = false)
  // initially set the selected form controls to the formarray
  this.empDetails.services.map((x) => this.ssArray.push(this.fb.control(x)))
}
```

Then you can add `[checked]="service.checked"` in template.

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6l1ztk?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

---

Option 2:

Keep your `checked` function like you have, just remember to add the prechosen values to your formarray. I don't really like this option, since for example, we end up calling a function in template, which is really not recommended. But anyway, keep the code as the same as you have now, just add the intial values to the formarray:

```
this.updateSvcForm = this.fb.group({
  sservices: this.fb.array([]),
});
// add the intial values to the formarray:
this.empDetails.services.map((x) => this.ssArray.push(this.fb.control(x)))
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-luc7m4?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

I added a console.log inside the function, to show how it is called. It's okay for a demo like this, but if you have a big form, I would **really** caution for you to use this solution.

---

There would be a third option, to actually set all values to your form array, and then just toggle the boolean value of the checkbox, but that would require some refactoring of code, which I don't know if you want. But there **is** that option too.

Answer (score 1):

you forget to set the new value of the form Array `sservices` :

```
onCheckChange(event) {
  const sservicesFormArray: FormArray =
    this.updateSvcForm.get('sservices') as FormArray;


  if (event.target.checked) {
    sservicesFormArray.push(new FormControl(event.target.value));
  }
  else {
    let i: number = 0;
    sservicesFormArray.controls.forEach((ctrl: FormControl) => {
      if (ctrl.value == event.target.value) {
        sservicesFormArray.removeAt(i);
        break;
      }
      i++;
    });
  }
  // set the new value of sservices form array
  this.updateSvcForm.setControl('sservices', sservicesFormArray);
}
```

Comment: I will try but i doubt it work. As this is onCheckChange is triggered only if a checkbox is checked manually.

Answer (score 1):

the "easy" way is to create a FormArray with values true/false. see the example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1fmrge?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Update**:Correct some errors

You fill the formArray using the data and the sservicesOptions

```
getFormArrayService(data:any[]):FormArray
  {
    //e.g. data=['mopping','washingclothes']
    // return a FormArray and the value will be [false,true,false,true]
    //if data=null, return a FormArray [false,false,false,false]
    return new FormArray(
       this.sservicesOptions.map(x=>new FormControl(data?data.find(dat=>dat==x.value)?true:false:false))
    )
  }
```

So, you can, in ngInit make some like

```
ngOnInit()
  {
    this.updateSvcForm=new FormGroup({
      sservices:this.getFormArrayService(null)
    })
  }
```

And in submitting the form, transform the value

```
  submit(updateSvcForm)
  {
      if (updateSvcForm.valid)
      {
          let services:string[]=[];
          updateSvcForm.value.sservices.forEach((x,index)=>
          {
              if (x)
                 services.push(this.sservicesOptions.value)
          })
          const result={
              ...updateSvcForm.value, //all value of the form but
              sservices:services
          }
          console.log(result)
      }
  }
```

The .html becomes like

```
<form *ngIf="updateSvcForm" [formGroup]="updateSvcForm" (submit)="submit(updateSvcForm)">
    <div formArrayName="sservices">
      <div *ngFor="let control of updateSvcForm.get('sservices').controls;let i=index">
        <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i"/>
        {{sservicesOptions[i].description}}

        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
    {{updateSvcForm?.value|json}}
```

The "not so easy way" a customFormControl, see an example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d2v9gj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcheck-box-group.component.ts)

Basically, we create a series of the checkbox, each change in checkbox return the "booleansToProp". In the example, I add a property "required", then indicate it is invalid if no check is checked and isString if we can return a string, not an array

```
@Component({
  selector: 'check-box-group',
  template: `
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of source;let i=index;let last=last">

      <div  [ngClass]="last?'form-group':''" class="form-check" >
         <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"  id="{{_name+''+i}}"
              [ngModel]="_selectedItems[i]"
             (ngModelChange)="setValue($event,i)" (blur)="onTouched()" >
         <label class="form-check-label" for="{{_name+''+i}}">{{item[_col]}}</label>
      </div>

      </ng-container>
  `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CheckBoxGroupComponent),
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CheckBoxGroupComponent),
      multi: true,
    }

  ],
  styles:[`
    .focused {
       outline: black dotted thin;
    }`
  ]
})
export class CheckBoxGroupComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() 
  set source(value)
  {
    this._source=value;
    //we need to know which column has the "value" and which column has the "text"
    //replace all extrange character else ":" and ","
    let aux=JSON.stringify(value[0]).replace(/[^\w|:|,\s]/gi, '').split(',');
    this._key=aux[0].split(':')[0]
    this._col=aux[1].split(':')[0]
  }
  get source()
  {
    return this._source;
  }

  _selectedItems: any[] = [];
  _source;
  _key: string;
  _col: string;
  _name:string="";
  _isString:boolean=false;
  _isRequired:boolean=false;
  onChange;
  onTouched;

  constructor(el:ElementRef) { 
    let name=el.nativeElement.getAttribute('name');
    //we store in this._isRequired if the element has an attribute "required"       
     this._isRequired=el.nativeElement.getAttribute('isRequired')!=null?true:false;
    //idem if the element has an attribute "isString" 

    this._isString=el.nativeElement.getAttribute('isString')!=null?true:false;
    //Is necesary give a name to the control if there're severals check-box-group
    this._name=name?name:"ck";

    }
  writeValue(value: any[]|any): void {
    this._selectedItems = this._isString?
       this.propsToBoolean(value?value.split(','):""):this.propsToBoolean(value);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
  }
  //setValue is called each time you check/uncheck a checkbox
  //Simple call to this.onChange with the value o the result of the
  //function this.booleanToProps
  setValue(value: boolean, index: number) {
    this._selectedItems[index] = value;
    this.onChange(this._isString?
         this.booleanToProps(this._selectedItems).join(','):
         this.booleanToProps(this._selectedItems));

  }

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null{
    if (!this._isRequired)
      return null;
    if (!this._selectedItems.find(x=>x))
      return {error:"you must select one option at last"}

    return null
  }

  //we received an array (or a string separated by commas) and
  //return an array of true/false
  propsToBoolean(props): any[] {
    let propsString=props?props.map(x=>''+x):null;
    return props ? this.source.map((x: any) => propsString.indexOf(''+x[this._key]) >= 0)
      : this.source.map(x => false);

  }

  //we received an array of true/false and return an array with the values
  //or with teh values separated by commas
  booleanToProps(propsBoolean: boolean[]) {
    let props: any[] = [];
    if (propsBoolean) {
      propsBoolean.forEach((item, index) => {
        if (item)
          props.push(this.source[index][this._key])
      })
    }
    return props;

  }

}
```

Comment: where do i call getFormArrayService?

Comment: services.push(this.sservicesOptions.value) and where does these value come from?

Comment: @Devora, I update my answer and make a stackbliz. I hope this help you