# FormArray in Angular - basics understanding

Tags: angular

My requirement is just this. As per code below, mainarray contain json array with each object having id and name. On click of multiple checkboxes and submit, i just need to log the selected ids. I am unable to figure out exactly , so please favour. What i tried is like below:

In html:

```
  <form [formGroup]="profileDetails" (ngSubmit)="onsubmit(profileDetails.value)">
    <div class="cov1" formArrayName="coverageIDs" *ngFor="let member of  mainarray;let i=index>
    <input type="checkbox" name"member" [formControlName]="i" [value]="member.id">{{member.name}}
    </div>
    </form>
```

In ts:

```
profileDetails=new FormGroup({
            coverageIDs:new FormArray([new FormControl('')])
   })
```

I surfed enough and i wasn't convinced with any . Even the above gives only one result true even when multiple checkboxes are selected due to model. Please correct me on these.

Comment: Look at your TypeScript code. How many FormControl does your FormArray contain? Just one. But you want many of them: one per element of mainarray. So, do just that. Make sure the FormArray has one control per element of mainarray.

Comment: yea you're right. only one form control here. that's why i get only one. I just kept this as base since this is only approach where i didn't get "couldn't find path"errors. Many actually required to be grouped inside coverageIDs .

Comment: Actually each need need to be pushed into form array as form control

Comment: I think you are mixing the "presentation" and the "form". take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984196/binding-data-to-angular-checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

you can use muti-selected in angular material. [angular_material_example](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples)

Comment: am sorry. i just kept the example simple. It's an already existing codebase and has so much details inside and i stick to reactive form.