# Angular 6 dynamic checkboxes keyvalue return array of IDs

Tags: arrays, angular, angular6, key-value, angular-reactive-forms

I have a list of dynamic checkboxes using keyvalue pipe that returns objects rather than just array of selected IDs.

can anyone help pls, I need the form to submit just an array of selected user IDs.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ciaxgj

**EDIT**
here's the log of a similar form with a multi-select (countries):
[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MREWQ.png)

I need `users` (checkboxes) to return an array like `countries` (multi-select) as in the log above.

Comment: Just do `console.log(Object.keys(this.userForm.value.users));`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984196/binding-data-to-angular-checkbox/55025983#55025983. tip, sometimes it's utils write in .html {{myform?.value|json}} to check the value of a form

Comment: Thanks, but that hasn't helped. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it happens that I have been overthinking the solution in thinking that like the multiselect,  checkboxes would/could return a ready array of selected items.

The rather simple solution was from reading another of Eliseo's posts combined with Jaba Prince's answer:

```
onSubmit() {
    var usersObj = this.userForm.value.users;
    var selectedUserIds = [];
    for (var userId in usersObj) {
        if (usersObj.hasOwnProperty(userId)) {
          if(usersObj[userId])//If selected
          {
              selectedUserIds.push(userId);
          }

        }
    }

    let data = {
      users: selectedUserIds
    }

    console.log(data);

    // post data in service call

  }
```

Many thanks to you two!

Comment: You could upvote and like the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your OnSubmit function to

```
onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.userForm.value);
    var usersObj = this.userForm.value.users;
    var selectedUserIds = [];
    for (var userId in usersObj) {
        if (usersObj.hasOwnProperty(userId)) {
          if(usersObj[userId])//If selected
          {
              selectedUserIds.push(userId);
          }

        }
    }
    console.log(selectedUserIds);
  }
```

Here is updated code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9fd17t

If you want to submit as a Form then add a hidden field to form

```
<input type="hidden" name="selectedUserIds" value=""/>
```

set value selectedUserIds from onSubmit and submit the form code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was able to get this far previously, but the issue still remains that the form submits objects. I have tried to update the form with setValue, patchValue, but none seems to work. I need the form to submit just the array of IDs. Any ideas pls? Am I approaching this all wrong?

Comment: Change button type to type="submit", Form submit may not work in stackblitz.com