# How to apply required validation for checkbox using dynamically

Tags: angular

I'm setting `dynamic form validation` using the following `JSON`. base on these `JSON` i have create dynamically form field using the following `JSON` format.

`fields = [
    {
      type: 'text',
      name: 'firstName',
      label: 'First Name',
      value: '',
      required: true,
   },
   {
      type: 'checkbox',
      name: 'hobby',
      label: 'Hobby',
      required: true,
      options: [
        { key: 'f', label: 'Fishing' },
        { key: 'c', label: 'Cooking' }
      ]
    }
  ]`

My `commponent.ts` file is following

```
form: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
  let fieldsCtrls = {};
    for (let f of this.fields) {
      if (f.type != 'checkbox') {
        fieldsCtrls[f.name] = new FormControl(f.value || '', 
          Validators.required)
      } else {
        let opts = {};
        for (let opt of f.options) {
          opts[opt.key] = new FormControl(opt.value);
        }
       fieldsCtrls[f.name] = new FormGroup(opts)
     }
   }
   this.form = new FormGroup(fieldsCtrls);
}
```

I have apply `required` validation for all input field exclude `checkbox`.

> How can apply required validation for the checkbox in this code?

Comment: you can use `setValidators([Validators.required])` after `opts[opt.key] = new FormControl(opt.value);` . or you can use the previous command `new FormControl(opt.value, 
          Validators.required)`

Comment: you also need to use `updateValueAndValidity()` on the FormControl

Comment: You'll first have to explain us what it means for a checkbox to be required. Either an option is false and the checkbox is unchecked, or it's true and the checkox is checked. What does required mean?

Comment: I want 1 checkbox checked is required when `required:true`

Comment: Hi Niladri I am not able to understand what you have suggested . I think if I have try this then it apply validation for every checkbox. I just want to minimum 1 checkbox checked is required when submit form

Comment: You'll need a custom validator on the form group to do that.

Comment: yes correct but i dont know how to create form froup with required validation.

Answer (score 0):

Bhagwat, you has no "value" in options. You need decided what do you want to get. Your code create a FormGroup that give you a value, e.g.

```
{firsName:"firstName",hobby:{f:true,c:false}}
```

But you can get some like

```
{firsName:"firstName",hobby:[true,false]}
```

Or

```
{firsName:"firstName",hobby:['f']}
```

In all case you need create a customValidator, and you need decided how you can show the form. For the first case you make the validator over the formGroup

```
 //when you create the formGroup of options
 fieldsCtrls[f.name] = new FormGroup(opts,this.oneRequiredValidator())

//I decided create the validator in the own component
oneRequiredValidator() {
    return (formGroup) => {
      if (!formGroup)
        return null;
      let oneChecked = false;
      for (let key in formGroup.value)
        oneChecked = oneChecked || formGroup.value[key]
      return oneChecked ? null : { error: 'one required' }
    }
  }
```

About the last option (return an array) I made a custom component some time ago, see [answer in stackblitz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984196/binding-data-to-angular-checkbox/55025983#55025983)

Comment: Hi @Eliseo i have implement it in my app but not working