# How to validate multiple checkboxes in Angular 7? It should throw a message , that atleast one checkbox should be checked

Tags: html, angular, typescript, validation, angular6

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row mb-1">
      <div class="col">
         Select Functions from the list below:<br />
           <div class="div-table mdle_rec">
             <div *ngIf="allFunctions.length > 0" class="div-table-row">
              <div *ngFor="let fnc of allFunctions;let i = index" class="div-table-col">
              <input class="checkbox align-middle mr-1" type="checkbox" id="{{'fnc'+fnc.FunctionId}}" [checked]="fnc.IsSelected" (change)="onFuncSelectionChange(fnc.FunctionId, $event)" required>
              <span style="font-size:16px">{{fnc.Description}}</span>
             </div>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Atleast one checkbox should be checked. If atleast one checkbox is not checked then it should throw an error.

Comment: Have you looked at Template Form or Reactive Forms validation. Esp. `FormGroup` ?

Comment: My requirement is for template driven forms. I've looked at many examples but I couldn't get what I wanted.

Comment: Can you reproduce a minimal version on stackblitz of whatever you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a getter function:

```
get someChecked()
{
   return allFunctions?allFunctions.some(x=>x.IsSelected):false
}
```

Use

```
<div *ngIf="!someChecked()">You sould check at least one</div>
```

Comment: It is not firing any validations

Comment: Weel if you want a more complex answer, you can make a custom control, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984196/binding-data-to-angular-checkbox/55025983#55025983

Comment: isAnyFuncSelected() {
    return this.curRole.Functions ? this.curRole.Functions.filter(x => x.IsSelected).length > 0 : false;
  }
should use filter and check length property..Thank you Eliseo

Comment: @Harish, "some(...)" return true or false, https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/some, filter(...) return an array -empty or not-